# I get "ORA-00904: invalid identifier" on function call despite being given GRANT EXECUTE

Tags: sql, oracle, function, ora-00904

I am trying to make a call to a IS_NUMBER function for the DSCRPT user name, but I've had to create the function in the DSCDBA login
I GRANTed EXECUTE permissions as I have on multiple other functions, but this one is raising an *INVALID IDENTIFIER* error

Function:

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION is_number (p_string IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN INT
IS
   v_new_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
   v_new_num := TO_NUMBER(p_string);
   RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
   RETURN 0;
END;
```

GRANT:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON "DCSDBA"."IS_NUMBER" TO "DCSRPT";
```

Executing SQL while logged in as DSCRPT

```
SELECT IS_NUMBER('123') FROM DUAL;
```

Error:

> ORA-00904: "IS_NUMBER": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

Confirmed I can see the function while logged into DSCRPT

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION') and owner = 'DCSDBA' order by owner, object_name;
```

[Return of ALL_OBJECTS search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZZdg.png)

Comment: Try to execute the funciton with its full name: SELECT DCSDBA.IS_NUMBER('123') FROM DUAL; Do you still get the error?

Comment: that worked, do you know why this time it wasn't working out the DCSDBA. part?
i've called the other functions I've without the full name

Comment: Seems like other functions are stored in DCSRPT schema, so you can use a short name to call them. Check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try make call

```
SELECT DCSDBA.IS_NUMBER('123') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: A little more explanation might make this a better answer.  Why wasn't the OP's call not working and why does adding the owner name fix it?  Also, maybe suggest a synonym.